# Old cartoon with boys hunting for eggs on the backs of birds

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

Back in the 90s/early 00s, when I was little, I happened to see 2-3 times on TV (in Greece), the following animation. I'm not sure if it's a part of a series, as it felt more like a stand-alone thing. It has a 70's eastern european aesthetics (like *Bolek & Lolek*, *Reksio*, etc).

The only thing I remember about the plot, is that there were some boys hunting for eggs in the sky, flying on the backs of birds, I think because of a tradition or festivity of their village. One of the boys keeps stealing the eggs of the protagonist, but in the end they become friends etc.

It's NOT *The Wonderful Adventures of Nils* (Holgersson).